# Create Table from HTML code

Tags: android

```
<table style="width: 560px; border: 2px solid #fee3cc; font-size: 1em;" rules="all" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">    
<tbody>   
<tr>    
<td>    
<p>Bharatiya Jana Sangh</p>    
</td>     
<td>     
<p>1951 - 1977</p>     
</td>   
</tr>   
<tr>    
<td>    
<p>Janata Party</p>     
</td>     
<td>     
<p>1977 - 1979</p>     
</td>     
</tr>     
<tr>     
<td>     
<p>Bharatiya Janata Party</p>     
</td>     
<td>   
<p>1980</p>     
</td>     
</tr>     
</tbody> 
</table>
```

I have the html code of table as above, and I want to directly show a new table on layout as above table code, how I can do this

Comment: What do you mean by directly show table like above? Are you showing this table inside webview?

Comment: yes i want to showing inside the webview

Comment: Ok now could you please rephrase your question?

Comment: how i add above code in web view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your activity:

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);
String yourHtml = "<html><body><table>...</table></body></html>";
webview.loadData(yourHtml , "text/html", "utf-8");
```